# remove item from cart through jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am removing item from cart through Jquery ajax and web services,but it is not removing. It is returning "System.String[]".

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public string ClearItem(string Img)
    {

                if (Session["Items"] != null)
            {
                string[] session_item_arr = Session["Items"].ToString().Split('|');
                for (int i = 0; i < session_item_arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] key_arr = session_item_arr[i].Split(',');
                    foreach (string item in key_arr)
                    {
                        if (item == Img)
                        {           
                            session_item_arr = session_item_arr.Where(val => val != session_item_arr[i]).ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                    bool item_inedx = Array.Exists(session_item_arr, x => x == session_item_arr[i]);
                    if (item_inedx)
                    {
                        Session["Items"] = session_item_arr[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["Items"] = session_item_arr;
                    }
                }

            } 
           return Session["Items"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Session["Items"]` session is **an array of strings** - not a string

So simple `.ToString()` not convert it to a line with strings separated by some comma. You need to convert it before return it back.

Take this example [C# Convert String Array to String](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-array-string) to correct this last line `Session["Items"].ToString();`

So convert it first to string.

a fast solution using [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___) is to return `return string.Join("|", ((string[])Session["Items"]))` but I am not sure how to split your items